# jQuery Selectable plugin on Touch Devices

Tags: jquery, touch, jquery-ui-selectable

I wrote a widget for selecting date ranges using jQuery because of the easy usage of the [selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) plugin, only to find out that it does not work for iPad and iPhone (and presumably other touch devices as well.

Is there any plugin / patch or *anything* I can use to get the code running on touch devices?

Comment: Have you tried adding the touch-punch plugin? https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

jQuery UI Touch Punch. It's a hack that turns touch events into click events. Should be perfect for what you're doing. The documentation is super clear and implementation is a simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
```

Give it a try!

EDIT: Fixed a spelling error

Comment: This doesn't work. The touch interface does not recognize the dragging action. Any ideas?

Comment: ok, actually it DID work. Might have been a caching issue the first time. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. This is an amazing plugin and saved me so many headaches.

Comment: How to select multiple options in case of touch device using selectable? On the desktop we use ctrl key to select multiple distinct values.